# Why does stripe card element not load up when using django stripe?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Hi I've been trying to learn how to build an ecommerce site and am getting stuck with the Django Stripe integration for a custom pay flow. I can get the pre built checkout to work but can't for custom pay flow.

Stripe seems to have updated the code on their docs a few months ago so when I try to look up tutorials, they all don't seem to have the same code and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. I'm self taught and just a beginner/intermediate maybe so might be missing something obvious.

I'm using the code from this page https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder and trying to convert it into Django.

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import stripe
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
# Create your views here.
from django.views import View


stripe.api_key = "xxxxxxxxx"


class StripeIntentView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            
            intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                amount=2000,
                currency='usd'
            )
            return JsonResponse({
            'clientSecret': intent['client_secret']
            })
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'error':str(e)})

def payment_method_view(request):
    

    return render(request, 'custom-landing.html')
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from products.views import payment_method_view,StripeIntentView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('custom-landing/', payment_method_view, name='custom-landing-page'),
    path('create-payment-intent/', StripeIntentView.as_view(), name='create-payment-intent'),

]
```

This is my Landing-page.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Accept a card payment</title>
  <meta name="description" content="A demo of a card payment on Stripe" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css" />
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
  <script src='{% static "js/client.js" %}'></script>
  <style>
    /* Variables */
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }

    form {
      width: 30vw;
      min-width: 500px;
      align-self: center;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0.5px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1),
        0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1), 0px 1px 1.5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
      border-radius: 7px;
      padding: 40px;
    }

    input {
      border-radius: 6px;
      margin-bottom: 6px;
      padding: 12px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1);
      height: 44px;
      font-size: 16px;
      width: 100%;
      background: white;
    }

    .result-message {
      line-height: 22px;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    .result-message a {
      color: rgb(89, 111, 214);
      font-weight: 600;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }

    #card-error {
      color: rgb(105, 115, 134);
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 17px;
      margin-top: 12px;
    }

    #card-element {
      border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
      padding: 12px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1);
      height: 44px;
      width: 100%;
      background: white;
    }

    #payment-request-button {
      margin-bottom: 32px;
    }

    /* Buttons and links */
    button {
      background: #5469d4;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
      border: 0;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 600;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      transition: all 0.2s ease;
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 5.5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
      width: 100%;
    }

    button:hover {
      filter: contrast(115%);
    }

    button:disabled {
      opacity: 0.5;
      cursor: default;
    }

    /* spinner/processing state, errors */
    .spinner,
    .spinner:before,
    .spinner:after {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .spinner {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 22px;
      text-indent: -99999px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      position: relative;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
    }

    .spinner:before,
    .spinner:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
    }

    .spinner:before {
      width: 10.4px;
      height: 20.4px;
      background: #5469d4;
      border-radius: 20.4px 0 0 20.4px;
      top: -0.2px;
      left: -0.2px;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 10.4px 10.2px;
      transform-origin: 10.4px 10.2px;
      -webkit-animation: loading 2s infinite ease 1.5s;
      animation: loading 2s infinite ease 1.5s;
    }

    .spinner:after {
      width: 10.4px;
      height: 10.2px;
      background: #5469d4;
      border-radius: 0 10.2px 10.2px 0;
      top: -0.1px;
      left: 10.2px;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 10.2px;
      transform-origin: 0px 10.2px;
      -webkit-animation: loading 2s infinite ease;
      animation: loading 2s infinite ease;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes loading {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }

      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    @keyframes loading {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }

      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      form {
        width: 80vw;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Display a payment form -->
  <form id="payment-form">
    <div id="card-element"><!--Stripe.js injects the Card Element--></div>
    <button id="submit">
      <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
      <span id="button-text">Pay now</span>
    </button>
    <p id="card-error" role="alert"></p>
    <p class="result-message hidden">
      Payment succeeded, see the result in your
      <a href="" target="_blank">Stripe dashboard.</a> Refresh the page to pay again.
    </p>
  </form>




</body>
</html>
```

This is what shows up on my http://127.0.0.1:8000/custom-landing/

[image]

I'm not sure why but the card elements aren't showing up.

I've only changed the python code. The javascript, html and CSS code are the same as on the Stripe docs.

Any idea on how I can get the card element to load?

And any feedback on whether the the django code is views is much appreciated.

Thanks

edit: This is the code that shows in my browser console.

[image]

line 10 of the client.js is

```
 document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console when you load the page?  If so can you update your question with the errors you see there?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help! I've added the errors from the browser's console.

Comment: Try moving`<script src='{% static "js/client.js" %}'></script>` from the `<head>` to just above the `</body>` line near the end of your HTML and try again.  It sounds like the JavaScript is running before your HTML is added to the DOM, so it can't find the `<button>`.